# Send data at once to view or consult remote data with ajax in select2

Tags: html, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm working in a big project, it has many forms, and forms have many elements.

Gender case only has 4 options, then I set it as: (I send all my values to my view at once)
`$('#gender').select2();`


Client case has 993324 options, then I set it as: (consult remote data via ajax) 
`$('#client').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: 'url/to/myclients',
    dataType: 'json'
...
  }
});`

I have other objects that has 100, 300, 5000, 10000, 50000.. and I dont know if send all data to my view or consult remote data with ajax?

What would be the correct way to work? in order to not slow view or make it difficult to use.

Answer (score 0):

The right is to **not populate the selects with all the posible responses**, instead, **keep them empty**, and **fetch the responses with ajax as the user types in search input**.

Example, the clients select2, you load it empty, when the user starts typing in the select2  search (onChange), make an ajax call that sends that input value to the server, and the server querys the database for the posible rows that has the value of the input and returns a json, then you populate the select2.

You can play with how many times or when the ajax fetch is triggered, for example, **trigger only when the user has wrote more than 3 characters**, wait few seconds between querys etc..

You also can **set a limit on the server query**, so even if they enter a name that is common, like John it only returns X values, and not all the thousands of clients with the John name.